# App runs slower when collection subview has a size increase?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, performance, uicollectionview

I am utilizing a UICollectionView for my universal app. Inside of each collection view cell I have a custom view, which ultimately hold's an image. Each cell is representing a playing card, so when tapped it flip's from front to back.The issue that I am having is when I scale up the size of that subview. If I have it smaller within the cell then everything run's fine. There are no slow down's of any kind. If I then scale up that subview to be larger then there are serious slowdown's. Not only while I scroll through the collection view up to down, but also when I tap the individual cell's. The lag happen's when a row of cell's comes from off screen. There is also lag when I tap a 'card' and it flip's from front to back.

This problem appear's to only exist on the iPad version of the app. When I run it on my iPhone there are no problem's at all in regards to lag.

Is there any reason as to why this would be happening?

Edit to add code:

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
                  cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Card" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    Card *card = [self.game getCardFromPlayAtIndex:indexPath.item];

    [self updateCell:cell usingCard:card withAnimation:NO];


    return cell;
}
```

Abstract method that is used above:

```
- (void)updateCell:(UICollectionViewCell *)cell usingCard:(Card *)card withAnimation:(BOOL)isAnimated
{
    // Using introspection to make sure that our cell is a PlayingCardCollectionViewCell
    if ([cell isKindOfClass:[PlayingCardCollectionViewCell class]]) {

        // If it is we an take that cell and cast it to a PCCVC and then pull out it's
        // outlet for the PlayingCardView
        PlayingCardView *playingCardView = ((PlayingCardCollectionViewCell *)cell).playingCardView;

        if ([card isKindOfClass:[PlayingCard class]]) {
            PlayingCard *playingCard = (PlayingCard *)card;

            playingCardView.rank = playingCard.rank;
            playingCardView.suit = playingCard.suit;


            playingCardView.faceUp = playingCard.isFaceUp;

            playingCardView.alpha = playingCard.isUnplayable ? 0.3 : 1.0;
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: You're using the reuse queue, right? Not trying to maintain the cells yourself?

Comment: I am indeed using reuse queue. There is no individual management for the cell's.

Comment: I've written test-cases for collection views that maintain very large datasets, so I don't think it relates to the CV per se. Just a WAG, but is there something about the rendering that is costly and when you scale up the view size, the cost becomes apparent?

Comment: It would help a lot if you could post all or some of the code in your "cellForItemAtIndexPath:" Most of the lag issues on CVs come from there and from access to the data source.

Comment: I'd bet it has to do with rescaling the images. That's usually the bottleneck.

Comment: I just added the code for that method @ReinierPelayo.

Comment: Definitely has to do with the alpha component change on the "playingCardView" that is one of the most expensive operations on UIKit. Just as a test, instead of changing the alpha, try hiding the view and see if it helps.

Comment: That alpha statement isn't even being applied in this context. That only get's applied if a match between card's is found. I found out the slowdown is coming from the graphic I am using for the back of the card. I took that statement out and it run's well. Why would that effect it so much? I am using the same image on the iPhone version and it has no effect at all. @ReinierPelayo